# MariaDB 10.x on CentOS 7?

Tags: centos, mysql, mariadb, centos7, rhel7

Why there is no MariaDB 10.x RPM for CentOS/RedHat 7?  How can I install it?

I'm trying to install the most recent stable version on my server, but it seems, that official repo is absent.

5.5 is included in the distro, that's right, but what about installing 10.x on CentOS/RHEL 7?

Comment: It is already expired. MariaDB released repository configuration for CentOS 7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An old question but this is no longer true.

Here is a link to the CentOS 7 + MariaDB 10.0 repo config tool: https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/#mirror=coreix&distro=CentOS&distro_release=centos7-amd64&version=10.0

Comment: Yep. Better late than never ;)

Answer (score 2):

Because it was not yet considered GA (stable) when RHEL 7 went into feature freeze (about a year ago).

If you need it, MariaDB provide their own yum repositories, including (now) for EL 7.

Comment: MariaDB does not currently provide any repositories for 10.X branch for CentOS7. And this is the problem. I understand why those repos have not made it into the CentOS base repos. But why they are absent at MariaDB website at all?

Comment: Really. I just checked and you're right. I wonder why they aren't doing that. It's a pretty significant oversight.

Comment: Yep. Strange issue.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the MariaDB repository.

for example:

```
# MariaDB 10.1 CentOS repository list - created 2015-11-22 17:27 UTC
# http://mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/
[mariadb]
name = MariaDB
baseurl = http://yum.mariadb.org/10.1/centos7-amd64
gpgkey=https://yum.mariadb.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-MariaDB
gpgcheck=1
```

and

```
yum install MariaDB-server MariaDB-client
```

source [install mariadb 10 or newer](https://der-linux-admin.de/2015/11/centos-7-mariadb-10-und-neuere-versionen-installieren/)

Answer (score -2):

you have to use repo [generator tools](https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/#mirror=mephi) and place the file inside `/etc/yum.repos.d/`